# [Keras]Some goes wrong when i create my Model

Tags: python, keras

When i use kears create my model,this error is occurring.
Scale3 Scale2 Scale1 are same operate.
The code is:

```
Scale3 = myconv2d(Scale3,255,1,1,'valid')
model = Model(inputs = X_input, outputs = [Scale3,Scale2,Scale1], name='YOLOV3')
```

Error is:[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0McCh.png)

myconv2d function is that

```
def myconv2d(X,f,size,s,stage,p = 'same'):
    X = Conv2D(f,kernel_size = (size,size),strides = (s,s),padding = 'same',name = 'conv2d_'+ str(stage))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3,name ='bn_' + str(stage))(X)
    X = K.relu(X,0.1)
    return X
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Do not include errors as an image. Just copy the text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply backend functions directly on Keras tensors, you need to use a Lambda layer for that:

```
def myconv2d(X,f,size,s,stage,p = 'same'):
    X = Conv2D(f,kernel_size = (size,size),strides = (s,s),padding = 'same',name = 'conv2d_'+ str(stage))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis=3,name ='bn_' + str(stage))(X)
    X = Lambda(lambda x: K.relu(x,0.1)(X)
    return X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use`layers.advanced_activations.LeakyReLU(0.1)(X)` to replace the code:`K.relu(X,0.1)`

Matias Valdenegro is also correct